# Using OpenQuery With INSERT INTO Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I currently use the following to data warehouse a table everday:

```
DROP TABLE mytable 

SELECT firstcolumn, secondcolumn INTO mytable
FROM OPENQUERY (mylinkedserver, 'SELECT firstcolumn, secondcolumn FROM linkedtable')
```

I would like to start using TRUNCATE going forward (to perserve system resources and indexes):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE mytable

INSERT INTO mytable (firstcolumn, secondcolumn)
?
```

How do I use OpenQuery with the INSERT INTO statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the syntax is:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE mytable

INSERT INTO mytable (firstcolumn, secondcolumn)
SELECT firstcolumn, secondcolumn 
FROM OPENQUERY (mylinkedserver, 'SELECT firstcolumn, secondcolumn FROM linkedtable')
```

Comment: I ended up using SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (mylinkedserver, 'SELECT firstcolumn, secondcolumn FROM linkedtable')

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(firstcolumn, secondcolumn)
  SELECT firstcolumn, secondcolumn
  FROM OPENQUERY
  (
    mylinkedserver, 
    'SELECT firstcolumn, secondcolumn FROM linkedtable'
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT INTO** by OPENQUERY seems to require **non-existing** table. An alternative is to use **INSERT INTO** which uses existing table but this one will also **either dump** the records ***over and over again*** (if there is no unique constraints on the destination table) or simply **refuse** to copy **any** record if **any duplicate** is detected.

But there is hope. If your objective is to update the table with only new records, the truncate may be an overkill. So, just treat this OPENQUERY as normal SQL by checking on the duplicate using *WHERE* clause. Something like this will do:

```
INSERT INTO mytable   
SELECT * from OPENQUERY(mylinkedserver, 'SELECT * FROM mytable_remote' ) rt 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE ID = rt.ID  
)
```

*We assumed that the constraint, non-repeating check, is on ID; select all is also used. Also the ODBC Drivers and linked-server setups are presumed ready.*

This should help with any such situation requiring updates of SQL Server table from remote data source. This can be set as a stored procedure and executed periodically.